# Implementing Jump forward in Unity3D

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

I believe that my problem is super simple but it's not simple for me right now. I need your help to implement a simple jump forward for the model from the Standard Asset(Ethan) who  has a bunch of different animations like *HumanoidFallLeft(Right), HumanoidJumpForwardLeft(Right), HumanoidMidAirLeft(Right) , HumanoidFall, HumanoidJumpUp, HumanoidMidAir* and *HumanoidIdleJumpUp.*

In the videos which I watched(for example this one https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ifw3u9ccdMY) I see that only jump, fall and land animations are used for the jump I need. Then these animations are grouped in the blend tree with the use of one parameter to regulate when to switch between animations. I have no idea what to do with the whole bunch of animations which are very short and not full - it looks for me that each of the clip includes 1 or 2 frames. I know I have to combine them somehow because I have the example of how to use it. It's in the standard ThirdPersonController Airborne Blend Tree [ThirdPersonAnimatorController - Airborne](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYMiW.png) but it's quite hard for me because it's connected also to the script with lots of parameters. but I need to make it simpler.

Now I use just the animation HumanoidMidAir which is just the jump up. But I want to create the jump which could have the direction(forward) to overcome obstacles. Any ideas, thoughts? I would really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

Unitys [Animator](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Animator.html) is what you are looking for.

So how do you do it?

You create a "chain" of animations in that animator.
The first animation in this row would be the "HumanoidJumpUp" followed by "HumanoidMidAir" etc.

You can also give these transitions triggers like a float property for movement speed and let the animator handle wether it plays walk or run animation. If a transition has no trigger it is automatically triggered by its predecessor.

So basically you want a transition from your walk or run animation into your jump sequence to achieve a smooth looking jump forward.

[image: Unity Animator]

You can tweak the way how these animation overlap etc.

But u definetly should have a closer look at that Animator thing ;)

Comment: I know this...
but the point is that the chain of these animations looks awful! :(
 anyway thank you

Comment: It is also possible to use an animation tool to combine your animations into a single one. You could do it with Blender, but i bet there are better/easier to use tools for that purpose.